# Spring Boot giving warning Custom isolation level specified but no actual transaction initiated

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am getting warning Custom isolation level specified but no actual transaction initiated when I use @Transactional annotation with isolation and propagation.But my query executes fine.Why method call is not coming under Transaction boundary.

```
    @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"com.mytest.txntest"})
    @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
    public class Application {

         public static void main( String[] args )
            {
                SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);        
            }
    }

    My Data Source Configuration looks like below.

     @Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
        @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.mytest.txntest" }, entityManagerFactoryRef = "testEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "testTransactionManager")
        @EnableTransactionManagement
        public class TestDBConfig {

            @Resource
            private Environment env;



            @Bean(name="testEntityManagerFactory")
            public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean testEntityManager(){

                LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

                entityManager.setDataSource(testDataSource());

                Properties properties = new Properties();


                properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect");
                properties.setProperty("persistenceProviderClassName", "org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence");

                entityManager.setJpaProperties(properties);
                entityManager.setPersistenceUnitName("Test_DB");
                entityManager.setPackagesToScan("com.mytest.txntest.entities");
                entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());

                return entityManager;

            }

            @Bean(name="testDataSource")
            public DataSource testDataSource() {
                DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder
                        .create()
                        .username(env.getProperty("test.username"))
                        .password(env.getProperty("test.password"))
                        .url(env.getProperty("test.url"))
                        .driverClassName(env.getProperty("test.datasource.driverClassName"))                
                        .build();
                return dataSource;
            }

            @Bean
            public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {

                HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateAdatper = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
                hibernateAdatper.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect");
                hibernateAdatper.setShowSql(true);
                return hibernateAdatper; 
            }

            @Bean("testTransactionManager")
            public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(@Qualifier("testEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityMangerFactory) {

                JpaTransactionManager jpsTxnManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
                jpsTxnManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityMangerFactory);


                return new JpaTransactionManager();
            }

        }
```

My DAO Class looks like below.

```
public TestDAO {

@PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) 
    {
        this.em = entityManager;
    }

    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) 
    {
        this.entityManagerFactory = emf;
        em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();        
    }


    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED,isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED,rollbackFor=Throwable.class)
    public Webacct getUserNameInfo(String userName,String dob) 
    {
    Query q = em.createNamedQuery("testQuery");
}
}
}
```

Am I missing any configuration. Using Spring Boot 1.5.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re using “NOT_SUPPORTED” propagation level which essentially executes the code inside that method without a transaction. You should use any other propagation level such as REQUIRED or REQUIRES_NEW.

Comment: Yes after changing propagation warning is gone.I think Spring should change this from warning to info level.